# Differentiability of $f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-e^{-xyt^2}}{t}$dt

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove the differentiability of this function in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$$
g(t)=\frac{1-e^{-xyt^2}}{t}
$$

is defined in $\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus 0$ and 
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} g(t)=0
$$

so $g(t)$ is continuous in all $\mathbb{R}$ and Riemann-int in $\mathbb{R}$. To prove differentiability what can I do? I can calculate $\partial_x f$ and $\partial_y f$

How can I calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}$?